# is it possible to make a stackView widget on api lower than 11?

Tags: android, api, widget, stack, stackview

i found some questions here about

```
StackView
```

and implement of the stackView on lower api , i cant use StackView even in my xml .

is it possible to make a stackView widget on api lower than 11 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to make a stackView widget on api lower than 11 ?

Not using the Android SDK alone, as `StackView` was not added to the SDK until API Level 11. You are welcome to see if somebody has created a backport of `StackView` that works on older versions of Android, though [the comments on this GitHub repo](https://github.com/arichiardi/ava-project) suggest that it will be rather difficult to backport.